# Hexify sha digest result without using hashlib

Tags: python, encryption, hash, sha256, hashlib

I've got digest value of data in string format, and I'd like to hexify it.

Here's the sample string `'\xf0z\xd8[\xfc\x7f'`

However, I cannot use `hashlib` since I don't have the original data from which the hash was created from.

trying `.digesthex()` on the string wouldn't work since `str` object don't have that method. Is there any alternative ?

Comment: `binascii.hexlify(s)` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each character in the original string, use `ord` to obtain the numeric value of the character and then use a string format operation to express that numeric value as a string containing a pair of hex digit characters.  Accumulate those two-digit strings into a single string.

```
    mystring = '\xf0z\xd8[\xfc\x7f'
    result = ''
    for ch in mystring:
        number = ord(ch)
        hexdigits = '{:02x}'.format(number)
        result += hexdigits
    print result
```

You can do all of that on one line by using a list comprehension to collect the pairs of hex digit strings into a list and then using the `join` method with an empty separator string to glue the hex digit strings together into a single string.

```
    mystring = '\xf0z\xd8[\xfc\x7f'
    result   = ''.join([ '{:02x}'.format(ord(ch)) for ch in mystring ])
    print result
```

Or instead of a list comprehension you can use `map` with a `lambda` to build the list of hex digit pairs.

```
    mystring = '\xf0z\xd8[\xfc\x7f'
    result   = ''.join(map(lambda ch: '{:02x}'.format(ord(ch)), mystring))
    print result
```

The `map` version is harder to read but it might run slightly faster.